# quero fazer um select no meu banco de dados para ver todos os resultados que sao: status = 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, where

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pagamentos WHERE status = 0";
while($aux = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
    echo '<td>'. $aux['nome_cliente'] .'</td>';
}
```

Comment: já trocou o status para 1 no where?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM pagamentos WHERE status = 1";

Comment: já consegui resolver, vlw